# QGIS is not launching in Debian Bookworm

Tags: qgis, installation, linux, debian, linux-mint

I have QGIS version 3.32 Lima installed in Debian. but it doesn't execute/launch. I don't get a satisfying error message.

So I tried to install the flatpak-version but that also won't run. Error message:

```
flatpak run org.qgis.qgis
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file)
: ignored.
Warning: Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running the latest LTR? Have you checked QGIS bug reports?

Comment: What is LTR? I searched for the error, but didn't find anything recent.

Comment: LongTimeRunning version of QGIS.

Comment: What does QGIS say when you launch it in a terminal?

Comment: Nothing. just:

user@user~$ qgis [no error-message]

                                                                                                  Or:

user@user:~$ flatpak run org.qgis.qgis
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Warning: Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket

Comment: sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common is required first https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html